# What is the meaning of "harboring cryptic" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "harboring cryptic" in this sentence?

> Tissue culture became more widely used at this time because of the introduction of antibiotics, which facilitated long-term cell line propagation, although many people were already warning against continuous use and the associated risk of **harboring cryptic**, or antibiotic-resistant, contaminations [Parker, 1961].

Comment: It isn't a phrase in itself. The risk was of harboring contaminations which were cryptic (hidden) or resistant to antibiotics.

Comment: @Kate Bunting could you tell me a substitution for harboring word?

Comment: Is "contain" a good substitution for harboring?

Comment: _Containing_ could be a substitute for the word _harboring_, though it doesn't have the same sense of _keeping hidden_.